# In the convolution layer (Conv1D and Conv2D) in Tensorflow, when set padding='same', which side is padded with 0?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

In `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` and `Conv2D`, the argument `padding` has the `'same'` option. I just want to know e.g., `Conv1D`, which side (the start or the end) is padded with 0 if the kernel_size=2 and stride=1.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `Conv1D`,

If the Number of Columns to be added (for padding, `p_i`) is even, both the Left and Right Sides will be Padded with 0, uniformly.

If the Number of Columns to be added (for padding, `p_i`) is Odd, Only the Right Side will be Padded with 0.

Number of Columns to be added can be calculated using the formula below:

```
Case 01: n_i%s = 0, p_i = max(k-s ,0)

Case 02: n_i%s != 0, p_i = max(k - (n_i%s)), 0)
```

where n_i is Input Shape (Number of Columns), p_i is Number of Columns to be added for Padding, s is stride and kernel size as k.